# What gene does the RAN-2 antigen correspond to?

Tags: gene, central-nervous-system

In many papers, immunopanning is performed against RAN-2, which stand for "rat neural antigen-2" ([some](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6782146/) [examples](https://academic.oup.com/brain/article/142/2/344/5289373)). It seems to have been first described by [Bartlett and colleagues in 1981](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000689938190593X) and to be a cell surface protein of astrocytes.

Apart from [a 1998 report](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1097-4547(19981015)54:2%3C147::AID-JNR3%3E3.0.CO;2-E) that it is a is "a GPI-anchored form of ceruloplasmin", I can't find any information about what gene or protein Ran-2 corresponds to. Is this known?

Searching on standard websites (eg [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=(RAN-2)+AND+%22Homo+sapiens%22%5Bporgn%3A__txid9606%5D+OR+%22Mus+musculus%22%5Bporgn%3A__txid10090%5D), [there](https://www.genecards.org/Search/Keyword?queryString=RAN-2) or [there](https://www.alliancegenome.org/search?q=RAN-2&category=gene)) do not yield relevant results.